# How to initialize an Array at the beginning of my class?

Tags: arrays, constructor

I am having a problem understanding what the Code exactly does.

My project contains some classes which are connected to each other in a certain form. 
Class Zoo - Class Vivarium - Class Animal

The idea is that we start from the Class Animal, create an animal which is contained in a Vivarium and a Vivarium is contained in the Zoo.

I want to handover an array of Animals to Vivarium and a Array of Vivarium to the Zoo Class. 
When I tried to program it I thought I can simply write

```
Animal[] inhabitants; (where inhabitants should be the name of the Array containing the     animals
```

or

```
Vivarium[] vivaria; (Same as above)
```

But to my question, what exactly does something like:   Vivarium[] vivaria;
Do at the beginning of my class? What happens when I write this?

Comment: I am sorry, but this site is not generally thought to be about learning programming. It is expected that you already have basic knowledge of programming and the questions cover specific issues of (usually) particular programming language.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I fully understand yor question but..
Vivarium[] vivaria; is declaration of array od Objects of type Vivarium. Nothing else.

You need to create instance of that array ad well as fill it. That line is only a declaration.

Comment: So I use this to let my class know that I will work with an array from the type Vivarium?

Comment: Exactly, moreover if that declaration is 'public' you will let other classes know about that.